# Is there an easy and cheap way to print qr codes on post-it notes?

Tags: print-design, barcodes

Is there an easy and cheap way to print small quantities of qr codes on post-it notes?
Would need only a few post-its with same qr code, but overall quantity might be a 100 a day.

Comment: Specific method depends on quantity. How much post-its do you need to make?

Comment: just edited a question per your comment.

Comment: I assume each day code will be different. Am I right?

Comment: pretty much so ..

Comment: Still not an answer per se, so I'll use a comment :). Have you tried to experiment with preparing a “template” sheet, sticking post-its to it and running it through the printer? I haven't but I would try it if I was in your situation.

Comment: Do they have to be on post its? Why not labels?

Comment: cause I will move these around on the wall

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the quantities you're talking about, I'd made a good use of my desktop printer. In fact I did a little test today using my “laser” ;). First I made a document of the size of my paper sheet. In my case it was A4. Then, knowing which edge goes to the drum first and which side of the paper faces it, I drawn a "placeholder" on my document: [image]

A placeholder's only purpose is to make orienting post-it easy. Of course there can be more of them and the sheet can contain some other information like marking of the “first” edge or marking the edge where post-it's glue should be, for example. Having it ready I did the first print.

Next I glued my post-it, making sure the glue was directed so it makes the drum first (non-sticky end to follow). In my document, I placed QRCode to be printed and hidden placeholder marks (no need to repeat them — it can be outright harmful result wise). So I got: [image]

I placed my sheet with post-it attached, oriented exactly as the first time in the tray and made the second print on it. The result was: [image]

The good part is that the glue remains sticky after going through the heater, so post-its can be used as intended right after “unsticking” them from the “template” sheet: [image]

That's pretty much it. I know it's relatively low-tech solution, requiring some manual work, but it still works and it's cheeeep :).

I don't think this trick will work for the inkjets, given their sideways movement of printing heads, but for most lasers I think it should be applicable.

Of course there will be some inaccuracies caused by inexact post-it placement on sheet, inexact positioning of the sheet in the tray etc., but if some care should be put into aligning independent elements these inaccuracies should be kept lower than, say, 2-3 mm. Results may vary depending even on printer construction, but hey!… it's not an offset printing press ;).

One more note: I'm not responsible for possible problems/damages/etc. AKA “bad things” that can potentially result from the experiments of the sort described above. I did it on my own responsibility and so will do every “follower” :).

Comment: This works. I have according to my logs printed somewhere between 150 - 900  Notes with aztec codes with this method with no problems so far. Another tip is that wide notes can be cut to size so its less work. I had to release one note from the fuser. Be sure to use the direct feed! Its guaranteed that the duplexer wont like this.

Comment: Oh and its also possible to buy just the glue, but our volumes are so low we dont care.

Answer (score 6):

There is actually a 3m product 
[Post-it® Notes PC410B, 8 1/2 in x 11 in Sheets of Notes for Printers](http://www.shop3m.com/70071213287.html?WT.mc_ev=clickthrough&WT.mc_id=shop3m-AtoZ-Post-it-Notes-for-Ink-Jet-and-Laser-Printers), but thbodzio low-tech solution seems to be more cost-effective.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like "PostIt" isn't necessarily what you're after. Why not just use a printable label sheet designed for this purpose. Something [like this](http://www.desktoplabels.com/category.aspx?cat=removable-labels). Then you can have them loaded in a dedicated tray (or printer) and use a template layout for quick output.

Comment: Sticking these labels to post-its could work as a medium-low cost, no risk alternative to thebodzio's no-cost, medium-low risk option

Comment: And for people on tight budget... You can also print multiple codes a normal sheet of paper and cut them to size. Than use Scotch removable tape to stick them to a wall.